# How do I multiply one list by another in every possible combination?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration

For example:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 6]
```

Wanted result:

```
NewList = [4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 12, 15, 18]
```

Comment: NewList =[] for item in list1: for item2 in list2: NewList.append(item1*item2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three possible approaches:

1. **Readable**

   ```
   new_list = []
   for a in list1:
       for b in list2:
           new_list.append(a * b)
   ```

   This makes it very clear what's going on, but requires four lines and repeated calls to `new_list.append()`, which is slightly inefficient.
2. **Concise**

   ```
   new_list = [a * b for a in list1 for b in list2]
   ```

   This is very compact, but for many people it takes a moment or two to remember whether the nesting of multiple-`for` [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) goes left-to-right or right-to-left.
3. **Lazy**

   ```
   from itertools import product

   new_list = [a * b for a, b in product(list1, list2)]
   ```

   This will work correctly even if `list1` and `list2` are [generators](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) or other one-shot, lazily-evaluated iterables, e.g.

   ```
   >>> from itertools import count, islice
   >>> list1 = islice(count(1), 3)
   >>> list2 = islice(count(4), 3)
   >>> [a * b for a, b in product(list1, list2)]
   [4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 12, 15, 18]
   ```

   ... which won't work with the first two approaches.

Note that I've used `new_list` rather than `NewList` in these examples, which is the conventional way to name variables in Python.

Comment: Just for fun, pushing all the work to the C layer in CPython, to avoid byte code execution: `from itertools import product, starmap`, `from operator import mul`, `new_list = list(starmap(mul, product(list1, list2)))`. In a local test case (with two 10 element inputs with small `int` values), pushing the work to the C layer like that reduced runtime by ~1/6 (and that stayed the case for 50x50; it might lose out for very small inputs, but that's it). General caveat applies: This is premature optimization, and the list comprehension is more Pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the result by printing `NewList`, which in this case can give you what you had above. Your `list1` and `list2` are initialized above this code just like you have above.

```
NewList = []
for item1 in list1:
    for item2 in list2:
        NewList.append(item1*item2)
```